# How to Disable Shipping info and method for custom product type in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom-product-type

I have created a custom product type extending simple product.I need to disable shipping information and shipping method for this product type on onepagecheckout just like it is disabled for virtual product. I cannot use virtual product and cannot extend from virtual product.

Please provide the any config or solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rewrite 2 magento classes:

`Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method` and `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`

**In you module `/etc/config.xml`**

```
<config>
.......
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method>Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method</onepage_shipping_method>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <quote>Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote</quote>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
........
</config>
```

**Your `Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php`**

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method 
{

    public function isShow()
    {
        return !$this->getQuote()->isVirtual() || !$this->getQuote()->isNonShippable();
    }

}
```

**Your `Model/Sales/Quote.php`**

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
{
    public function isNonShippable()
    {
        $isNonShippable = true;
        $countItems = 0;
        foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $_item) {
            /* @var $_item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
            if ($_item->isDeleted() || $_item->getParentItemId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $countItems ++;
            if ($_item->getProduct()->getTypeId() != 'YOUR_PRODUCT_TYPE_ID') {
                $isNonShippable = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $countItems == 0 ? false : $isNonShippable;
    }
}
```